# Failed to use "Regular Expression Extractor" capturing response header in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I would like to capture response Header value for "**Authorization**:".

```
Response headers:  
HTTP/1.1 200 OK  
Cache-Control: private  
Content-Type: application/json   
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5  
Authorization: Bearer MMSArOve7c9NffH4oTqBMW1SiWLUbQi2nm0ryR- 
                 Wi5d_plLkk7xzTVo8b5_s1sg-Rut6vdDoTvlRju-  
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319  
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET  
Date: Mon, 14 May 2018 03:50:47 GMT  
Content-Length: 484
```

and I did this.

[image]

but the result is

```
JMeterVariables:  
JMeterThread.last_sample_ok=true  
JMeterThread.pack=org.apache.jmeter.threads.SamplePackage@33a6821  
START.HMS=113828  
START.MS=1526254708675  
START.YMD=20180514  
TESTSTART.MS=1526269844536  
Token=test  
__jm__Thread Group__idx=0  
__jmeter.USER_TOKEN__=Thread Group 1-1
```

what I did wrong, please help Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex to extract Authorization

```
Bearer (((.*)\n)+)X-Asp
```

And Use Match No 1

[image]

[image]

For More information you may link to the following

[JMeter Regular Expressions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)

[Extracting variables](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2016/01/jmeter-extract-and-re-use-as-variable/)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `^` which is [Start of String Anchor](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)

> Applying ^a to abc matches a. ^b does not match abc at all, because the b cannot be matched right after the start of the string, matched by ^

So use the regular expression without it:

```
Bearer(.*)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove `^` character from your regular expression

[image: JMeter Reuglar Expressions]

More information:

- [Regular Expressions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [Perl 5 Regex Cheat sheet](https://perlmaven.com/regex-cheat-sheet)
- [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter)